# How to modify hyperbolic function to get area between bounds

Tags: integration, area

I have a formula to calculate the (real world) temperature distribution over a fin heated at one end that is radiating heat, and I would like to modify it to generate the average temperature of the fin (or the area under it).

$$
\begin{align} 
T(x) &= \frac{\cosh(m(L-x)) }{\cosh(mL)} (Tfin-Troom)+Troom \\
\\
m &= \sqrt{\frac{hP}{kA}}
\\
\\
\end{align}
$$

$P = 2*(fin\ width+fin\ height) $
$A = fin\ width * fin\ height (looking\ end\ on\ at\ the\ fin) $
$x = position\ down\ fin\ from\ heated\ end $
$h = convection\ heat\ transfer\ coefficient\ W/(m^{2} k) $
$k = fin\ thermal\ conductivity\ W/(mK) $
$L = fin\ length\ (from\ hot\ to\ cold\ end)$

T(x) is the temperature at distance x from the heated edge. Obviously the temperature is dropping as x increases to L distance which is the cold end of the fin.

To calculate the total heat emitted it seems I should get the average temperature of the fin, although this might be a slight approximation it should be good enough.

I dimly remember I should be able to integrate the formula to get the area but that was so many years ago I have not got a clue as to how to approach it now. I guess what I want is the average T (or area under T) for x=0 to L.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I imagine you mean the mean value theorem for integrals: $T_{prom}=\frac{\int_a^b f(x)dx}{b-a}$

Comment: Looking that up I don't understand it but it seems its related to the tangent of the arc from what I can tell - I am after the area under the slope, to give an average temperature of the fin.